# Math function with three variables (correlation)

Tags: multiple-regression

Helloo !
I want to analyse some data in order to program a pricing algorithm. Following dates are available:

[image]
I need a function/correlationfactor of the three variables/dimension which show the change of the Median (price) while the three dimensions (pers_capacity, amount of bedrooms, amount of bathrooms) grow. e.g. Y(#pers_capacity,bedroom,bathroom) = ..

note: - in the screenshot below are not all the data available (just a part of it) - median => price per night - yellow => #bathroom

e.g. For 2 persons, 2 bedrooms and 1 bathroom is the median price 187$ per night

Do you have some ideas how I can calculate the correlation/equation (f(..)=...) in order to get a reliable factor?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may be looking for is a regression algorithm (correct me if I am wrong). I have actually done something similar before and my approach was to use a mixture of gaussians model to approximate the behavior of my data (you will need to test several combinations of gaussian functions) and then I used that trained model to predict the median price. Be aware that this approach is generative and it will assume the data is generated by a Gaussian function, which may or may not be the case!

Comment: Could you elaborate on how a "mixture of Gaussians model" can be considered a "regression algorithm"?  How would it be applied to these data?

Comment: One can use a set of Gaussian functions over the feature space to model the behavior of the median price given those features (considering you have a large data set to estimate the Gaussian functions' parameters). Then you can use that model to make predictions on new observations

Comment: OK--but that doesn't sound like a regression model and it doesn't sound like it could work with the small dataset presented in the question.

Comment: It definitely would not, I am assuming the dataset is much larger (because the question states that there is more than what the screenshot posted shows). Would you simply apply a Least Squares model? Maybe it is the easiest solution, but with a large dataset and for real data I personally would rather try out something else